# Picasso with new Target loads bitmap from second time

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit, picasso

Below is my code. During navigating to the screen for the first time onPrepareLoad() gets called. But it does not come to onBitmapLoaded() or onBitmapFailed(). Could some one lighten up. Is it loading only from Cache always?  How to handle it. I am using only default Cache mechanism. No external memory involved.  Where as if i navigate second time on the same screen/ fragement, the bitmap gets loaded through onBitmapLoaded()

```
    picasso.load(url)
            .noFade().into(new Target() {

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                relativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(
                        bitmap));
                relativeLayout.invalidate();
            } else {

                relativeLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(
                        bitmap));
                relativeLayout.invalidate();
            }
            if (true)
                Log.d("onBitmap", "onBitmapLoaded");
            //
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            //
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            //
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, i achieved the requirement by placing a ImageView inside the Layout and i passed on my Layout width and height to scale my ImageView.  Reason is getMeasuredWidth of my ImageView is always 0, where as my Layout gives me the measuredWidth and measuredHeight ( Parent of the ImageView)

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/c_details"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_small">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/c_details_view"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_small">
            </ImageView>

           <!--   Other Views goes here      -->

        </RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
            In my Fragement java file
            RelativeLayout cDetailsLayout = (RelativeLayout)                                                 rootView.findViewById(R.id.c_details);

            // passing following into Picasso call
            cDetailsLayout.getMeasuredWidth(),                 cDetailsLayout.getMeasuredHeight()
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not getting callbacks inside your Target is because it is being garbage collected. Picasso keeps a weak reference to it. It is stated in the doc to the into() method: "This method keeps a weak reference to the Target...". So you have to store Target yourself in a field.